# How to call a shell script from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, shell

We were working on a project and wanted to call a shell script from JavaScript. We tried to look for help online but were unable to find any good example for the same. Can someone point is in the right direction ? We tried `child_process.exec`, but we were unable to get anything out of it.

Comment: Shell script on the clients computer or are you talking about node.js or sth?

Comment: Shell scripts on the clients computer

Comment: What JavaScript environment? A browser? Something else?

Comment: The poster is obviously talking about node.js: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 1):

No. It would be such a gigantic security hole that any browser developer who allowed this would be [family-friendly censorship banner].

The right answer to this is [Why do you want to do that?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by l0b0, this isn't possible directly. You would need to set up some kind of web service on the server that the JavaScript can call. This service would then in turn call the shell script. But be careful.